# Strange behavior with Qt stacked widgets on Mac OS + OpenGL

Tags: macos, qt, opengl

I’m working on a OpenGL application on OS X and have run into a wall. The application uses a simple QTabWidget to collect data that is then displayed in the last tab through a OpenGL view. Everything works fine on Linux where I usually develop but compiling on Mac I get a really strange behaviour.

I’ve created a Minimal Working Example [here](http://maigo.se/files/mwe_mac_opengl.zip) that shows the strange behavior I get on Mac.

In short, when the user traverses each tab and gets to the last OpenGL view things get funky. Gui elements disappear, mouse events gets sent to the wrong tab, and the OpenGL view is generally unresponsive. I’ve tried a multitude of approaches to try to fix this or at the very least circumvent it but without luck. And there seems to be little or no information of related cases on the web.

I've tried Qt5.0.2 and Qt5.1.0 with the same result, and compiling on OS X 10.8.

I would appreciate any help I could get in the matter, a fix would be awesome, an alternative solution equally perfect.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known Qt 5 bug. I've posted [a different testcase for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444431/mouse-events-blocked-because-of-qgl-view/18448191). I don't know yet if anyone has bothered actually reporting it to qt-project (I haven't).

This bug is a regression from Qt 4.8, BTW.